# Restful service naming convention for service

Tags: rest, naming-conventions, restful-architecture

I have a service connecting to an enterprise service which I have no control over. The service requires I make a call to it to initiate a ping to a device and then make subsequent calls to it to get the status. After 20 or so seconds I will get the status back.

I have been thinking of a rest pattern and just getting stuck on the fact that it is not truly restful Id like to reach out for feedback and get some opinions. I could just do a normal get /device/status and hit it over and over again? Or i could break up the call into /device/ping and /device/status or something like that. Any ideas are appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: You may want to review: https://www.infoq.com/articles/webber-rest-workflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For status, REST standards would suggest a format of `'/device/{deviceId}/status'`. But if the enterprise service you are connecting to does not support multiple devices; you could go for `'/device/status'` with 'GET' http verb.

You could use `'/device/status'` with 'HEAD' http verb as an exposure for the ping call

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to return the a JMS queue URL in location header in API response. Usually, in device management applications, separate JMS server is deployed. Make use of it - if it's there.

Take a hint from [here](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos-space-sdk/13.1/apiref/com.juniper.junos_space.sdk.help/JSDeviceManagerSvc/Docs/rest.discover-devices.html).

.